# Stacked bar chart bars dimension is not coralated to Y axis

Tags: c3.js

I am trying to build a stacked bar chart using c3.js.

The issue I have is that the bars that get generated are not coralated to the Y axis.

This is what I have so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZLMoY?editors=1010

And this is the code:

```
c3.generate({
  bindto:'#chart',
     data: {
        type: 'bar',
        columns: [
           ['Column 1', 2, 10, 22, 34, 9, 60],
          ['Column 2', 6, 15, 43, 36, 45, 75],
          ['Column 3', 10, 20, 79, 39, 50, 97],
          ['Column 4', 12, 27, 87, 76, 55, 150]
        ],
        groups: [
          ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4']
        ],
      },
      bar: {
        width: 15,
      },
      axis: {
        x: {
          show: true
        },
        y: {
          show: true,
          padding: {
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
          },
          tick: {
            //count: 6
          },
          min: 0,
          max: 150
        }
      },
      grid: {
        x: {
          show: true
        },
        y: {
          show: true
        }
      }
});
```

As you can see the bar chart is generated but it is not generated correctly. The last 4 bars are all equal even if the values that are provided are not.

Taking into consideration that the Y axis has the maximum value set to 150 then the 2nd, 3rd and 4th bars should not ocupy the same height as the 5th bar

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **axis.y.max** value is less than stacked sum, so chart is clipped at the top.

Try this:

```
c3.generate({
     ...
      axis: {
        ...
        y: {
          ...
          min: 0,
          max: 500
        }
      }
   }
```

Or [see it in action](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOVXOY?editors=1010).